# MinHeap implementation in c#

Tags: c#, heap

I am working on a MinHeap implementation for school and I have encountered a problem. The code typically works well but sometimes generates an argument out of range exception in my heapify method. I have tried to isolate the problem but I am a terrible debugger.

Here is my code for the function:

```
    private void Heapify(int i)
    {
        int least;
        int leftchild = 2 * (i + 1) - 1;
        int rightchild = 2 * (i + 1);

        if (leftchild < heap.Count &&  (heap[rightchild].CompareTo(heap[i]) < 0))
        {
            least = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            least = i;
        }

        if (rightchild < heap.Count && (heap[rightchild].CompareTo(heap[least]) < 0))
        {
            least = rightchild;
        }

        if (least != i)
        {
            T temp = heap[i];
            heap[i] = heap[least];
            heap[least] = temp;
            this.Heapify(least);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of range exceptions are generally easy to track down. Basically, you have to make sure that whenever you're accessing an item in an array via indexes, said array's count / length is greater than the index. In other words, ensure that in every call to heap[#index], #index < heap.Count (either by straight checking it or by your method's logic)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (leftchild < heap.Count &&  (heap[rightchild].CompareTo(heap[i]) < 0))
```

If `rightchild >= heap.Count`, this will give you an exception.